# I need to sum certain nodes in xslt based on the index and value of sibling nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, sum, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

In the xml structure below I need to use xsl to sum the values of each record type's costs if the record type is "ADD"

```
<records> 
   ...irrelevant nodes...
   <recordType>NO</recordType>
   <recordType>ADD</recordType>
   <recordType>ADD</recordType>
   ... irrelevant nodes...
   <LdgCost>1</LdgCost>
   <LabCostIn>2</LabCostIn>
   <LabCostOut>3</LabCostOut>
   <LdgCost>4</LdgCost>
   <LabCostIn>5</LabCostIn>
   <LabCostOut>6</LabCostOut>
   <LdgCost>7</LdgCost>
   <LabCostIn>8</LabCostIn>
   <LabCostOut>9</LabCostOut>
   ...irrelevant nodes...
</records>
```

(the record type's costs are the elements below in the same index as the record type). This means the recordType in the first position that is of type "NO" does not need to be added so its values

```
<LdgCost>1</LdgCost>
<LabCostIn>2</LabCostIn>
<LabCostOut>3</LabCostOut>
```

do not need to be summed. However, the next two record types are "ADD" and therefore I need to sum the values of

```
<LdgCost>4</LdgCost>
<LabCostIn>5</LabCostIn>
<LabCostOut>6</LabCostOut>
<LdgCost>7</LdgCost>
<LabCostIn>8</LabCostIn>
<LabCostOut>9</LabCostOut>
```

and set that as my total. Output would just be a total element

```
<total>39</total>
```

Logically the structure that the above xml structure represents if it were using parent-child nodes is as follows.

```
<records> 
   <record>
       <recordType>NO</recordType>
       <LdgCost>1</LdgCost>
       <LabCostIn>2</LabCostIn>
       <LabCostOut>3</LabCostOut>
   </record>
   <record>
       <recordType>ADD</recordType>
       <LdgCost>4</LdgCost>
       <LabCostIn>5</LabCostIn>
       <LabCostOut>6</LabCostOut>
   </record>
   <record>
       <recordType>ADD</recordType>
       <LdgCost>7</LdgCost>
       <LabCostIn>8</LabCostIn>
       <LabCostOut>9</LabCostOut>
   </record>
</records>
```

However instead of using this structure I have to base the parent child relationships based on the index of the sibling elements.

The way I would do this manually is as follows:

1. Find the first `<recordType>` element, Check if value is ADD or NO. Since value is NO I skip this one.
2. Find the next `<recordType>` element, Check if value is ADD or NO. Since value is ADD then I would need to find the 3 costs related to this second record. These cost elements are guaranteed to exist and be in the index corresponding to their recordType.
3. Find `<LdgCost>`[2] element value and add it to sum. (the index is two because we are on the second recordType since we skipped the first one and its costs were ignored)
4. Find `<LdgCostIn>`[2] element value and add it to sum.
5. Find `<LdgCostOut>`[2] element value and add it to the sum.
6. Now that we have added the three costs from the second record to the sum and we move on to the third `<recordType>` element and check its value. Since the value is ADD we find the 3 costs associated to the third record.
7. Find `<LdgCost>`[3] element value and add it to sum.(the index is three because we are on the third recordType)
8. Find `<LdgCostIn>`[3] element value and add it to sum.
9. Find `<LdgCostOut>`[3] element value and add it to the sum.
10. There are no more `<recordType>` elements to process so we return the sum of 39.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: Each record has a type and 3 costs associated with it.  The record type at index 1 is of type "NO" so that three costs at index 1 (LdgCost, LabCostIn, LabCostOut) do not need to be summed. The record type at index 2 is of type "ADD" so the three costs at index 2 need to be summed. The same goes for the record type and costs at index 3.

Essentially I want to do something like: for each record type if type is ADD then sum all costs at the same index as the current record Type

Comment: How do you determine that a "record" has 3 costs, and not 2 or 5?

Comment: So each record has three costs. 1,2,3 are part of the first record type "NO". 4,5,6 are part of the second record type "ADD". 7,8,9 are part of the third record type "ADD"

Each record type has the three costs (LdgCost, LabCostIn, LabCostOut) So the first three nodes (values 1,2,3) after the record nodes are "children" (although they do not have a parent-child structure) of the recordType NO node and they represent the costs for the first record. However, the node type is NO so we exclude them from the sum.

The next two record types are ADD so we include each of their 3 costs in the sum.

Comment: There are always the same number of costs per record. So if there are two elements of recordType there will be 6 costs (3 per each record). If there is one record type there will be 3 costs. etc.

Comment: michael, I added an addition to the original question at the bottom to show a more logical representation of what the xml I have to use is trying to represent.

Comment: I am still puzzled whether the costs always come in groups of 3 or can the size of the group change from case to case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the element names you can use

```
<xsl:template match="/records">
    <xsl:variable name="positions" select="index-of(recordType, 'ADD')"/>
    <total>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(LdgCost[position() = $positions]
            | LabCostIn[position() = $positions]
            | LabCostOut[position() = $positions])"/>
    </total>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Good answer. Voted up.

Answer (score 1):

***--- edited in response to clarifications ---***

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/records">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="index-of(recordType, 'ADD')" />
    <xsl:variable name="costs" select="LabCost | LabCostIn | LabCostOut" />
    <total>
        <xsl:copy-of select="sum($costs[(position() - 1) idiv 3 + 1 = $i])"/>
    </total>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So this would work if those were the only nodes in my xml. I simplified the question. There are also other nodes in this xml that I find the records and costs in.

The xml looks more like some xml elements, then the recordType nodes, then some more irrelevant nodes and then the costs for each recordType. So there is other data in there but it still holds true that there will be 3 costs per recordType element and that the costs will be linked to the recordType with the coorresponding index.

Comment: I have to do something more like for each record type get the index of the record type releveant to the other record types (whether it's the first, second, etc) and then if it is of type ADD find the cost element (LdgCost, LabCostIn, LabCostOut) node with that index and add the to the sum.

Comment: I appreciate your patience as this is not very straightforward to explain either.

Comment: Well, you need to provide a way to identify those costs. Ideally, you should provide step-by-step instructions how to do this manually, from start to finish (without relying on the intelligence or common sense of the one performing the instructions).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a way to identify the costs. I have added step by step instructions to the best of my ability to the bottom of the original question.

Comment: I mean how to separate the costs from the irrelevant nodes. You say "*find the 3 costs related to this second record*". I don't know how to do this manually.

Comment: So I believe if you could do a for each on the <recordType> elements and as the for each is going over them then you can just reference the costs by name and current index like so: LabCost[1], LabCostIn[2], etc. You don't need to actually find them. As long as you know the index you just give it the name of the element and the index and it will return your value. I just don't know how to put this all together in xslt.

Comment: "*reference the costs by name*" But I don't know the name.

Comment: The names of the 3 costs are LabCost, LabCostIn, LabCostOut. You will see these three for each recordType element.

Comment: I also see `LdgCost`. Can one assume that a "cost" is an element whose name contains "Cost"? Or do you have  better test for separating them from the other, irrelevant elements?

Comment: Sorry about that. That was a typo on my end. The three cost elements are LdgCost, LabCostIn, and LabCostOut. For each recordType element there will be these three costs. A cost element is best going to be identified by those three names. We can't assume anything that contains "Cost" will be a cost element because there is an element called EstTotalCost.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I did not follow the procedure you have outlined, because that would require summing each recordType individually before getting the grand total. Looking at it from the opposite direction is much shorter.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, You may not be aware that from all answers yours is the only one that produces wrong result? All other answers produce `39` when applied on the provided XML document. Your answer produces `23`. Before accusing anyone of "spiteful downvoting", please, try to produce correct solutions.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev My answer produces 39 after you correct the input so that "*the names of the 3 costs are LabCost, LabCostIn, LabCostOut*" as stated by OP here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899273/i-need-to-sum-certain-nodes-in-xslt-based-on-the-index-and-value-of-sibling-node/37900336?noredirect=1#comment63255563_37900336

Comment: @michael.hor257k, The comment you refer to says: "The three cost elements are LdgCost, LabCostIn, and LabCostOut." So, it is `LdgCost`, not `LabCost`

Comment: So it's this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899273/i-need-to-sum-certain-nodes-in-xslt-based-on-the-index-and-value-of-sibling-node/37900336?noredirect=1#comment63255401_37900336 In any case, I would expect OP to make the necessary adjustment - and I would expect you to find more serious reasons for downvoting than a typo that's not even mine.

Answer (score 1):

**The wanted sum can be expressed as a single XPath 2.0 expression**. Below are two different such expressions:

```
sum(/*/*[name()=('LdgCost', 'LabCostIn', 'LabCostOut')]
           [for $vPos in ceiling(position() div 3)
             return 
               /*/recordType[$vPos] eq 'ADD']
   )
```

**or**:

```
sum(for $vAddPositions in index-of(/*/recordType, 'ADD')
      return
        /*/*[name()=('LdgCost', 'LabCostIn', 'LabCostOut')]
               [ceiling(position() div 3) = $vAddPositions]
   )
```

**Here is an XSLT 2.0 - based verification** (the transformation just outputs the results of evaluating these two expressions):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
    "sum(/*/*[name()=('LdgCost', 'LabCostIn', 'LabCostOut')]
               [for $vPos in ceiling(position() div 3)
                 return 
                   /*/recordType[$vPos] eq 'ADD']
        )
    "/>

    =====================

    <xsl:sequence select=
    "sum(for $vAddPositions in index-of(/*/recordType, 'ADD')
          return
            /*/*[name()=('LdgCost', 'LabCostIn', 'LabCostOut')]
                   [ceiling(position() div 3) = $vAddPositions]
         )
    "/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<records> 
   ...irrelevant nodes...
    <recordType>NO</recordType>
    <recordType>ADD</recordType>
    <recordType>ADD</recordType>
   ... irrelevant nodes...
    <LdgCost>1</LdgCost>
    <LabCostIn>2</LabCostIn>
    <LabCostOut>3</LabCostOut>
    <LdgCost>4</LdgCost>
    <LabCostIn>5</LabCostIn>
    <LabCostOut>6</LabCostOut>
    <LdgCost>7</LdgCost>
    <LabCostIn>8</LabCostIn>
    <LabCostOut>9</LabCostOut>
   ...irrelevant nodes...
</records>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
39

=====================

39
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this give you what you need:

Using XSLT 1 and MSXML

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    >
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <!-- create a set of node for all the values that need to be added -->
      <xsl:variable name="values">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="records/recordType"/>
      </xsl:variable>
        <!-- at this point $values contains a fragment with groups of
        <LdgCost>value</LdgCost>
        <LabCostIn>value</LabCostIn>
        <LabCostOut>value</LabCostOut>
        -->
        <total>
            <!-- sum up all the values -->
           <xsl:value-of select="sum(msxsl:node-set($values)/*)"/>
        </total>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="recordType[.='ADD']">
      <!-- the index for the ADD recordType -->
      <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()"/>
      <!-- select costs using index -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="/records/LdgCost[$index]"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="/records/LabCostIn[$index]"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="/records/LabCostOut[$index]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm using a node-set function here and that will be different for each xslt processor.

Using you data, it returns a single node:

```
<total>39</total>
```